# Is there a way to implement a wcf service connected to a database without paying for azure?

Tags: database, wcf, azure, windows-phone-8

It seems like everything that I read is saying that for Windows Phone 8 Development, in order to create a database that connects to my WCF Service, I need to pay for it (Azure). Is that the truth?

I want to create a database that my mobile app can access but I do not want to pay the money for it. Is there somebody on here who could fill me in on this?

If I am able to create a database that connects to my WCF service for free, could someone point me in the right direction to accomplish this?

Comment: No, you can create your own hosting provider. You can do it for free.

Comment: WCF services can use any database they like, or no database at all. It has nothing to do with Mobile or with Azure.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: That being said, would I create the database in the same solution that the WCF service is in then or do I create the database somewhere else and then have the WCF service access the data?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an Azure pricing question (or one asking for a list of free Azure services, which again is pricing-based, and is a moving target).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some interesting articles about WCF Services in Windows Phone world.

- [How to consume an OData service for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg521145%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Using WCF Service in Windows Phone 8.1 (same in Windows Phone 8)](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/893352/Using-WCF-Service-in-Windows-Phone)

Now you can host the WCF Service in your own server, hosting provider or anything else.

Comment: That first article is very helpful. If I created the database with OData would I be able to make it an image database that I can add and delete images from a windows phone 8 app? If so, could you once again point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can search it https://www.google.com/search?q=Odata%20working%20with%20images&rct=j